# PAL Wizard for Biztalk Performance How to find out which process is using the most available memory

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, biztalk

While checking the performance of Biztalk application using PAL,I observed that performance counter \Memory\Available MBytes has raised an alert.However I am not able to find out what is the actual process or program which is causing this.

I can see the below information along with the details of the performance counter,but there is no info on who or which process is causing it.

Alerts
An alert is generated if any of the above thresholds were broken during one of the time intervals analyzed. An alert condition of OK means that the counter instance was analyzed, but did not break any thresholds. The background of each of the values represents the highest priority threshold that the value broke. See the 'Thresholds Analyzed' section as the color key to determine which threshold was broken. A white background indicates that the value was not analyzed by any of the thresholds.
Time Condition Counter Min Avg Max Hourly Trend

Comment: not programming related, and not even enough specific information to answer!

Answer (score 0):

PAL might be referring to the BizTalk memory thresholds used in [throttling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559893%28v=bts.70%29.aspx). If you run a perfmon against these counters, you can see how much memory each of your BTSNTSvc's is consuming, as well as the threshold levels which will cause throttling, and the current throttling states of your process, if applicable.

From firsthand experience, BizTalk throttling on memory conditions is a really bad thing